# Position divs under each other with change in browser width

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs that I want to position a certain way as the browser window gets smaller. As the divs move under each other, I want them to push all the way to the left, and under the div on the previous line without extra space. The divs can be different in height based on how much content is inside of them.

here is my css for the divs:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 190px;
  max-height: 450px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

please check out these images for a visual reference.

[image: narrow browser]

[image: narrower browser]

Comment: *you must remove the `float` prop and set `vertical-align: top` prop*

Comment: I did that and then added column width to the parent div. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use  flexbox, flex-wrap:wrap, it's the easiest way to do many things, check this:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Grid is another option and you can study how it works to better understand that logic.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/